# Passing a parameter to a thread but get I get completely different results than anticipated

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, parameter-passing

I am completely new to C, so excuse me for my lack of knowledge. I am trying to make 4 threads that will each generate a number between 100-199 200-299 300-399 and 400-499 for each of the threads respectively. However when I pass my parameter interv which is a struct type with two int values, I get something completely different on the other side. For example when I send in 100 and 199, I get 0 instead of 199 and -13216 instead of 100. I am not sure where exactly the problem is, here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 4
int sum; /* global variable shared by thread(s) */
pthread_mutex_t counter_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;


int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

typedef struct interval {
    int min;
    int max;
} interval;

void *runner(struct interval *param); /* threads call this function */
/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t workers[NUM_THREADS];
    interval *interv;
    interv->max = 199;
    interv->min = 100;
    /* create the thread */
    printf("min = %d max = %d \n",interv->min,interv->max);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        printf("min = %d max = %d \n",interv->min,interv->max);
        pthread_create(&workers[i],NULL,runner,&interv);
        interv->min += 100;
        interv->max += 100;
        /* wait for the thread to exit */
        pthread_join(&workers[i],NULL);
    }
    printf("sum = %d\n",sum);
    return (0);
}

/* The thread will begin control in this function */
void *runner(struct interval *param) {
    int n, array[100], list_sum, counter;
    printf("min = %d max = %d \n",param->min,param->max);
    for (int i; i < 100; i++) {
        n = rand() % (param->max + 1 - param->min) + param->min;
        array[i] = n;
        list_sum += n;
    }
    qsort(array, 100, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);
    for (int i; i < 100; i++) {
        counter += 1;
        if (counter == 10) {
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&counter_lock);
    sum += list_sum;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&counter_lock);
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

**UPDATED:** 
So I did not get the result I expected when the program compiled, so I re-wrote most of my code. Although now, again, I am getting some strange behavior and I am not sure why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 1
#define NUM_ELEMENTS 10
//Sum computed buy the background thread
int total = 0;
int counter = 0;

struct sum_runner_struct {
    int min;
    int max;
    int array[NUM_ELEMENTS];
    int answer;
};

//Thread function to generate a sum of 0 to N
void* runner(void* arg) {
    struct sum_runner_struct *arg_struct = (struct sum_runner_struct*) arg;
    int n, sum;
    for (int i = 0; i<NUM_ELEMENTS; i++) {
        n = rand()%(arg_struct->max + 1 - arg_struct->min) + arg_struct->min;
        printf("%d ",n);
        arg_struct->array[i] = n;
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i<NUM_ELEMENTS; i++) {
        sum = sum + arg_struct->array[i];
        printf("%d ", arg_struct->array[i]);
        counter += 1;
        if (counter == 10) {
            printf("\n");
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Sum: %d\n",sum);
    arg_struct->answer = sum;
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int INTERVALS[4][2] = {{100,199},{200,299},{300,399},{400,499}};
    struct sum_runner_struct args[NUM_THREADS];

    // Launch threads
    pthread_t tids[NUM_THREADS];

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        args[i].min = INTERVALS[i][0];
        args[i].max = INTERVALS[i][1];
        //Create attributes
        pthread_attr_t attr;
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);

        //Create Thread
        pthread_create(&tids[i], &attr, runner, &args[i]);

    }

    //Wait until thread is done its work
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_join(tids[i], NULL);
        printf("Sum of thread %d is %d\n", i, args[i].answer);
        total += args[i].answer;
    }
    printf("Sum is %d\n", total);
}
```

Before you comment on my random number generator, I know that it is not the best solution as of now, but that is not my issue. My issue is when I add the numbers in the array for a thread I get a number that is bigger by 6 integers. I am not sure why this happens.

For example when I run the program with a single thread to generate 10 elements I would get something like this:

```
133 143 162 129 100 108 152 156 156 119 
133 143 162 129 100 108 152 156 156 119 
Sum: 1364
Sum of thread 0 is 1364
Sum is 1364

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 57ms)
```

Note that I printed the array twice hence why there are two lines of the same array. As you can see (I think I added them up right) if you add the numbers in the array you would get 1358, not 1364. I am not sure what causes this.

Comment: The prototype of your function should be `void *runner(void *param);`.

Comment: NOTE: I think I may have found the issue but cannot seem to find a solution. When I am sending the argument interv, I realize I am sending &interv which is a pointer to a pointer hence why the values may differ. But when I remove the &, I simply get 

    RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 1s)

Comment: You never allocate memory for `interv`.

Comment: not sure how that is causing an issue, because outside of the function runner everything seems to be working fine, I get the right values for min and max when I print them outside of the function, but inside the function numbers become funny.

Comment: It is undefined behaviour, so it is possible that it works in main and not in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the issue, I am not sure exactly why, but when I initialize 
    int n, sum;
for some reason sum value is initialized to 6. Can anyone explain why this happens?